# How can I cut text from the end of a variable up until a specific character?

Tags: javascript, string

How can I cut text from the end of a variable up until a specific character?

Like this:

```
a_a_a
```

And I want the last "A" and split the text at the last "_":

```
a_a_ | a
```

Then I want to get 2 strings witch would be like this:

```
string A = a_a_
string B = a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`lastIndexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp) to get the last occurance of the character to be searched and then [`substr`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) to get the string from that index

```
var str = "a_a_a";
var startIndex = str.lastIndexOf("_"); //Here we are getting the last index of _ char
var result = str.substr(startIndex); //this will output `_a`
var result = str.substr(startIndex+1); //as we need only `a` we are using `startIndex + 1`
```

Comment: THANKS, but in 2 strings or could i use: result[0] and result[1]

Comment: @12345, what are you asking? Do you want to search for 2 strings?

Comment: @12345: You can use `substr` to get both strings. All you need is the index of the last `_` which you know how to get now... read the documentation and apply what you learned!

Comment: just failing with the enter button, sorry!

Comment: Ahh thanks dude! I've tried to mixing around with the indexOf thingy and now I asked for it and got an answer :)

Comment: @12345 When you print the variable `result` from the code you will get the `output` as `a`

Comment: I need it for the +/- button on my calculator

Comment: But how can I get the first string: "a_a_"

Comment: @12345, Instead of `lastIndexOf` try using `indexOf`

Comment: And what does the +1 mean cause the last "a" could also reprecent things like "aaa"

Answer (score 0):

One way;

```
var a = s.substr(0, s.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);
var b = s.substr(a.length);
```